# "UI updates were forcibly disabled by application"

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working a new version of one of my apps, Time Out, which uses a login item helper for scheduling.  A couple of my alpha testers are reporting memory leaks and excessive CPU usage... but I can't reproduce either.

In particular, they mention sluggish performance, and a lot of console logging like the following.  What could be causing this?

```
1/18/14 3:06:21.754 PM WindowServer[139]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "com.dejal.timeout.scheduler" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
1/18/14 3:06:21.986 PM WindowServer[139]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "com.dejal.timeout.scheduler" after 1.23 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
1/18/14 3:26:54.418 PM WindowServer[139]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "com.dejal.timeout.scheduler" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
1/18/14 3:26:55.122 PM WindowServer[139]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "com.dejal.timeout.scheduler" after 1.72 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.01 seconds)
1/18/14 3:31:21.083 PM WindowServer[139]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "com.dejal.timeout.scheduler" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
1/18/14 3:31:21.197 PM WindowServer[139]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "com.dejal.timeout.scheduler" after 1.12 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this error can be caused by taking too long inside of -drawRect: or some other part of the drawing machinery. It’s most likely a symptom, not the root problem—the root problem is your drawing is super-slow.

Get their data files if you can. If not, make a special build with timing built into it, in the simplest way possible. Like, just insert NSLog()s at various points that say where they are, and have the users e-mail you the console logs after the app’s been sluggish.

Comment: Thanks Wil.  I don't do any custom drawing in the affected app; the only UI is a NSStatusItem menu.  And disabling that didn't solve it.  It doesn't seem to be a data issue either.  So I'm exploring the console logging, app samples, etc.  No luck so far, though.